# Facing some EF Core version issue after upgrading from .NET Core 3 to .NET 8

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I have upgraded my application from .NET Core 3 to .NET 8. When I tried to run my application, I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a..

I need a solution for this

Comment: Have you upgrade the enityframeworkcore packages?

Comment: Please at least share your .csproj files.

Comment: After upgrading EF core package to 8  this problem solved.thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors usually indicate package version mismatch. Be sure to upgrade/consolidate package versions especially EF Core ones (based on problem with one of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` types).